# Smart pointer operator[] "no match" when type is array with known length

Tags: c++11, smart-pointers

Given the below code:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[SHA256::DIGEST_SIZE]> sha256hash;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const sha256hash &hash) {
    // Save old formatting
    std::ios oldFormat(nullptr);
    oldFormat.copyfmt(os);

    // Set up formatting
    os << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::hex;

    // Do our printing
    for (int i = 0;i < SHA256::DIGEST_SIZE; i++)
      os << hash[i];

    // Restore formatting
    os.copyfmt(oldFormat);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const sha256hash&)’:
error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘const sha256hash {aka const std::unique_ptr<unsigned char [32]>}’ and ‘int’)
   os << hash[i];
```

I thought that the typedef would give me a smart pointer containing a pointer to an array of uint8_t and so operator[] should be indexing into that array. My best guesses at what's happening is that I'm instead saying that I want a unique_ptr to a pointer to an array of uint8_t. I think I see a couple of ways out of this but I'm not sure which is best

1. `typedef std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> sha256hash;`
   compiles, but I'm not entirely sure that my overloaded operator won't try to print *any* unique_ptr to an array of ints.
2. I make a container struct for the int array, and put a unique_ptr around that.

Comment: seems that the `operator[]` is very specifically defined for `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` and does not work for `std::unique_ptr<T[N]>`, so `typedef std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> sha256hash;` seems to work

Comment: You could very specifically use a custom deleter like  `typedef std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[], MyDeleter> sha256hash;` if accidental overloads are your concern

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up going with option 2. I'll post my changes in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to @PeterT's [input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45654492/smart-pointer-operator-no-match-when-type-is-array-with-known-length/45654902#comment78267424_45654492) I ended up going with my second option. A custom deleter seemed too far out of my way, and this was fairly easy to integrate into my already existing code. Here are my changes:

```
//! Light wrapper around SHA256 digest
class SHA256Hash {
  //! The actual digest bits.
  uint8_t buff[SHA256::DIGEST_SIZE];
public:
  //! Pointer to a hash.
  typedef std::unique_ptr<SHA256Hash> ptr;

  //! Default constructor
  SHA256Hash() : buff() { }

  //! Operator to offer convenient buffer access
  uint8_t &operator[](const uint8_t i) { return buff[i]; }

  //! Operator to offer convenient buffer access
  const uint8_t &operator[](const uint8_t i) const { return buff[i]; }

  //! Offers access to the underlying digest
  uint8_t *get() { return (uint8_t *) &buff; }
};

// Delegate to the version that prints references
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const SHA256Hash::ptr &hashp) {
  os << *hashp;
  return os;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const SHA256Hash &hash) {
    // Save old formatting
    std::ios oldFormat(nullptr);
    oldFormat.copyfmt(os);

    // Set up formatting
    os << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::hex;

    // Do our printing
    for (int i = 0;i < SHA256::DIGEST_SIZE; i++)
      os << (int) hash[i];

    // Restore formatting
    os.copyfmt(oldFormat);

    return os;
}
```